# Adding items outside of allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a class Set:

```
class Set
{
public:
    //Default constructor
    Set ();

    //Some more functions...

private:
    int *p;
    const int K = 10;
    int numval = 0; //Number of ints in the array

    //Other variables...
};
```

The default constructor:

```
Set::Set()
{
    p = new int[K]; //Allocate memory for array with 10 ints
}
```

If I in some other function would fill the array with 10 ints and then add an other one, what would happen? The compiler doesn't crash and I'm able to print the 11:th int. But since I havn't allocated memory for it, where is it stored?

Example:

```
Set1 += 5;
```

Would add 5 to the array with the following operator overloader.

```
const Set& Set::operator+=(const int x)
{
    p[numval] = x; //Add next int after the last int in the array
    numval++; //Increment number of ints
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Out of bounds array access is undefined behavior, period. If you're not doing that, it should be fine. Of course, I'm obligated to mention that you should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Your code has a bug in it. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't warn you at compile-time, you may use tools that detect the error at run-time. For example [LLVM's sanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/index.html).

Comment: The compiler doesn't crash, but the process (your program being executed) might crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I in some other function would fill the array with 10 ints and then add an other one, what would happen?

You'd write into whatever memory came after the end of the array, causing undefined behaviour: perhaps causing no obvious problems, perhaps corrupting some unrelated data (or the metadata used to manage the heap), or perhaps crashing if there was no writable memory there.

> But since I havn't allocated memory for it, where is it stored?

It isn't stored anywhere, in the sense of having storage allocated for it. There's just nothing to stop you writing to arbitrary memory locations beyond the end of an array. Be careful not to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Computer memory is linear. It's one huge row of cells (bytes). Every cell has 2 neighbours (except the first and the last ones, obviously). Allocating memory is just an act of telling "this part is mine". It's really nothing more than a promise: you promise to not write outside your plot and in return you get promise noone else would write inside it. So what happens when you write outside of your allocated area? You break your promise. There may be someone's else's plot right next to yours, there might be unused space. Nothing really happens when you write outside your area. Real problem arises when rightful owner comes back and tries to pick up what he left - and it turns out to be something else, something you put there. (Of course it's possible that your plot lies next to something system considers important. In that case, OS stations guards on the border, and they shot to kill any trespassers on sight.)

It is your job as a programmer to make your program keep it's promises. When processes break their promises, bad things may or may not happen - to them or to other processes.

Comment: There are many wrong statements in your answer. 1st of all _"computer memory is linear"_

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it's obvious that my explanation is a big simplification. However please do elaborate how computer memory is nonlinear, especially how it's of any concern when dealing with an array of 10 ints.

Comment: plus one for nice oversimplification :-)

Comment: @MartinBa Thanks. I tried to recall the state of my mind 15 years ago when I first discovered that `p[-1]` "works" : )